# Download all gems dependencies

Tags: ruby, rubygems, compass-sass

I want to install compass by downloading any required file and taking them to another machine **without internet connection**. I have downloaded the source package for compass and when I run gem on it in the non connected machine it complains about missing dependencies. Any solution?

Comment: I don't know what your use case is, but if you aren't using Bundler yet, I bet it will solve some of your problems. It's simple to get started and is a breath of fresh air.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

That's precisely the problem I had.

After searching around for a while I found a solution that works using Bundler https://bundler.io/

Getting Gem with Dependencies:

- Create a new Folder with a File named `Gemfile`.
- Write a Source and the Gem you want to have the dependencies for into the File
- Example:

  > source "http://rubygems.org" 
  > gem 'rails', '3.2.1'
- Open a Commandline at this Folder and Execute: `bundle install`
- This should download and install all dependencies
- Execute the Command `bundle list` if you wanna see it
- Execute the Command `bundle package`
- This should create the Directory Structure `vendor/cache`
- Inside the cache directory are now all the dependencies you need for your gem

Install Gem on Machine without internet connection:

- Copy the cache Folder to the Machine
- Open a Commandline inside the Cache Folder and execute **gem install --local Gemname.gem**
- Example:

> gem install --local rails-3.2.1.gem

Comment: Does this also acquire transitive dependencies? i.e. dependencies of your dependencies?

Comment: I think it downloads the dependencies of your dependencies except for those that are required only for developing the gem itself (refer to John Bachir's answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402819/download-all-gems-dependencies#answer-4405072)

Comment: Thank you so much! This saved me a LOT of time!

Comment: Note: You don't need to run "bundle install" first.
"bundle package" on its own will download all of the dependencies you need to transfer the gem to another machine.
You can then install these gems with "gem install --force --local *.gem" before installing your own gem

Comment: With `bundle package --no-install` it will skip the installation.

Comment: In your third bullet point, what does "Bsp" mean?

Comment: @MartinThurn: Bsp is a short form of the german word "Beispiel". I used it unintentionally because I am a german native speaker. I corrected it by using the equivalent english word "Example". Thanks for the question.

Comment: On Ubuntu you too need the build-essential package.

Answer (score 4):

I did

```
export GEM_HOME=.
export GEM_PATH=.
gem install --no-ri --no-rdoc --install-dir . <gem>
```

Answer (score 3):

Hm. That's a little tough. `gem dependency` will show you dependencies for one gem, but it won't go all the way down the tree.

```
➔ gem dependency compass
Gem compass-0.10.5
  haml (>= 3.0.4, runtime)

Gem compass-0.10.6
  haml (>= 3.0.4, runtime)

➔ gem dependency haml   
Gem haml-3.0.21
  maruku (>= 0.5.9, development)
  yard (>= 0.5.3, development)

Gem haml-3.0.22
  maruku (>= 0.5.9, development)
  yard (>= 0.5.3, development)

Gem haml-3.0.23
  maruku (>= 0.5.9, development)
  yard (>= 0.5.3, development)

Gem haml-3.0.24
  maruku (>= 0.5.9, development)
  yard (>= 0.5.3, development)
```

"development" means it's only required if you are developing the gem itself. "runtime" means you need it to use it.

so in this case, the only dependency is haml. if it were a more complicated gem, i don't know a good way to generate the whole tree.

Comment: FYI: There are some new dependencies in compass v0.11