# How do I easily download Bundler and all its dependencies?

Tags: ruby, bundler, dependency-management

According to the question "[Download all gems dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402819/download-all-gems-dependencies)", if I want to download all of a gem's dependencies I can use Bundler to do the hard work for me. This works really well for most gems, but when I try to do this with Bundler it doesn't download anything to `vendor/cache`, presumably because Bundler assumes that when the bundle gets deployed Bundler will already be present.

I'm not too fussed about bundling anything up right now, I just want to pull down bundler-*.gem and all its dependencies without having to manually trawl through the dependency tree.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what your question is. Are you asking how to install Bundler?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your question, you want to specify bundler path for saving gems. Bundler downloads all gems to `$BUNDLE_PATH` or `$GEM_HOME` paths by default. If you want to change it, you have to add i.e. `--path vendor/bundle` option to install gems to `vendor/bundle` directory. Remember that bundler will remember this setting until you specify `--system` option to change it.

You can read more about bundle install options in [bundle install documentation](http://bundler.io/bundle_install.html).

Comment: Sorry, I think you've misunderstood; Bundler currently depends on a small pile of gems. I'd like an easy way to download all of these `.gem` files by some means other than working through the dependencies myself.

Comment: Bundler does not have any dependencies of its own, other than a Ruby interpreter.